# Spectrum of an upper triangular matrix.

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, banach-algebras

Consider the algebra $A$ of upper triangular matrices. Given

$$a= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}\\0 & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n}\\ 0 & 0 & \dots & a_{3n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$

I claim that the spectrum $\sigma(a) = \{a_{11}, a_{22}, \dots, a_{nn}\}$. I managed to show that $a_{11}, a_{22}, \dots, a_{nn}$ are all in the spectrum. Is there a way to show that the spectrum can not contain more elements?

Basically if $\lambda \notin \{a_{11}, \dots, a_{nn}\}$, my idea is that we can 'solve' the equation $(\lambda-a)b = b(\lambda-a) = I_n$ for some $b \in A$ by writing out the associated system of equations, but I want a cleaner less computational approach.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: You have to show that an upper triangular matrix with non-zero diagonal entries is invertible. Probably the easiest way to do this is to compute its determinant. But it is also not very hard to show that a vector in the kernel must be zero (start with the last entry and work your way up recursively).

Comment: @MaoWao Yes, but I need that the inverse is also an upper triangular matrix, which complicates things no?

Comment: You're right, I did not read carefully enough. In this case you can use the spectral permanence theorem: https://planetmath.org/SpectralPermanenceTheorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see this is the following (if you have heard about characteristic polynomials).

The characteristic polynomial of $a$ is the polynomial

$$
P(\lambda) = \det (\lambda I_n - a) = \prod_{k=1}^n(\lambda - a_{kk})
$$

where the second equality comes from the fact that the determinant of an upper triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal elements.

Now it is clear that the roots of $P$ are exactly $a_{11}, \dots, a_{nn}$ so
$\sigma(a) = \{a_{11},\dots,a_{nn} \}$.

Comment: This shows the eigenvalues are $a_{11}, \dots, a_{nn}$, so $\sigma_{A}(a) \supseteq \sigma_{M_n(\Bbb{C})}(a) = \{a_{11}, \dots, a_{nn}\}$. I think the key observation is that the inverse of an upper triangular matrix (if any) is again upper triangular).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by $\sigma_A(a)$, could you clarify that? If $\lambda \in \sigma_{\mathbb R}(a)$ then by definition there exists a non-zero vector $x \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $ax = \lambda x$ and it follows that $a - \lambda I_n$ is not invertible and thus $\lambda$ is a root of $P$ the characteristic polynomial of $a$. This gives you the other inclusion if I am not mistaking

Comment: Yes, but the invertibility is in $A$! It is possible (maybe?) that $a - \lambda I_n$ is invertible in $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ but not in $A$.

Comment: Ohh okay I understand, let me think about that!

Comment: But I think that's resolved by using the following: if an upper triangular matrix is invertible, then its inverse is also upper triangular. But I have to write out the details :)

Comment: Yeah if you are okay with directly using this result you problem is solved ;) Actually, it is even quite simple to show that the inverse of an upper triangular matrix is also upper triangular, just write $ax = y$ as a linear system of $n$ equations and write each $x_k$ as a function of $y_k, \dots, y_n$, starting by $y_n$, then $y_{n-1}$, and so on

Comment: Thanks for the help!